# Was Caliban helping with mutant capture?

Tags: plot-explanation, x-men-cinematic-universe, logan

In the film Logan, was Caliban helping Alkali Transigen capture mutants? I remember a dialogue mentioning so. If so why and what made him stop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a Marvel Comic Character Caliban was originally a villain; this is no real surprise, as many Marvel heroes began their tenure as evil do-ers (the Avenger Hawkeye amongst them!)

The fact he previously used to help transigen track mutants could be a reference to his Comic Book Origin Story, or the fact that he has appeared (although in a markedly different guise) in the continuity already; here is a screenshot of him from *Age of Apocalypse*:

[image]

Whilst *Logan* director James Mangold has gone on record to state that the two depictions of [Caliban were accidental](http://nerdist.com/heres-why-caliban-appears-in-both-logan-and-x-men-apocalypse/), he has made no efforts to clear up whether they are explicitly unrelated characters (more likely to not been seen undermining another film as less canonical, rather than to establish a direct link between them).

So in both Movie and Comic book appearances, Caliban has previously debuted as 'a villain'; this is upheld in Logan.

Given that Transigen's ultimate goal was to remove Mutants from the world, and this was a hidden agenda (likely hidden from Caliban), it's not unreasonable to assume he would have had a 'change of heart' at some point whilst working for them.